# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" when trying to make a Chrome extension with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a Chrome extension in React using create-react-app. When I load the extension to Chrome, and clock inspect popup to try to get popup.html to run on the console, it tells me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" on popup.js line 1 which is the import react line.

From other questions here I believe the problem is that when using ES6 I have to run the app with npm start, but how would this work when trying to make an extension instead of a web app? Is there any way? Since I need to load the unpacked extension into chrome then how would npm start help?

Here are the relevant files:

manafest.json:

```
{
  "short_name": "Timer",
  "name": "Website Viewing Timer",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "React Ext"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

popup.html:

```
<h1>test</h1>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
```

popup.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Timer extends Component {
  render() {   
    return <h1>hello</h1>;
  } 
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Timer />,
  document.body
);
```

I just took a react tutorial so I may be missing something obvious, but I appreciate any help.

Comment: `popup.js` is not javascript, that is `jsx`, which has to be transpiled to `.js`, look into babel and/or webpack.

Comment: But shouldn't initializing the files with create-react-app have handled the webpack and babel?

Comment: You need to run `npm run build` to generate the actual js.  Idk where it will save it to though, but whatever file it creates is what you need to load

Comment: Ah, I apologize for not being more detailed in the original post. To load the unpack extension on chrome, I do `npm run build` which saves a build folder at the root of the project folder. I load that build folder when loading unpacked extension on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after some more googling I was able to fix this by adding the attribute `type="text/jsx"` to the script tag in popup.html. Though I'm actually not 100% sure why this works. Is it because I needed to flag popup.js as a JSX file in order for babel to translate it?